# java loop adding increments of 100

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, int

This might be a dumb question but I cannot seem to figure it out.

If I am using a loop and start a int such as c at 1 and I want it to display number 1-2000 in increments of 100. ex.

```
1
100
200
300
400
500
etc.
```

What would I write for the c=c+?

Comment: The 1st increment is 99.

Answer (score 5):

You have one problem - you can't start with 1 and then go 100, 200, ... without a special case.

```
for (int c = 100; c < 2001; c += 100) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`c++` is the same thing as `c = c + 1`. The increment there is `1`. So, quite simply:

```
c = c + 100
```

Note, changing `1` to `100` is *not* an increment of `100`.

Answer (score 0):

c+=100 would work too. Same as writing c = c + 100

Answer (score 0):

If you had initial value for c of 0, i would suggest just to simply c=c+100, until c==2000. Since you want a different increment for the first one, I would try to do this bit of pseudo-code:

```
    c=1
    while (c!=2000)
    {
    // check remainder from integer division by 100
    int remainder = c%100;

    c = c + (100-remainder);

    // your cool piece of code
    }
```

Sorry for bad indentation, its 3 AM here ;).

So that code gets your current index, eg. c=1, calculates the remainder of integer division by 100 remainder (99), and adds it no next value of c (1+99 = 100).
next iteration will work since the remainder will be 0, and thus it will increment another 100!

Happy coding